# Alterar dinamicamente variável CSS dentro de uma iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

tenho a variável dentro do iframe definida assim:

```
:root {
  --color_bg: #ffffff;
}
```

Quero alterar essa variável CSS do lado de fora, ja tentei:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var iframe = $('iframe');
        $('.title', iframe.contents()).html('teste'); //FUNCIONA
        $(":root", iframe.contents()).css("--color_bg", '#000000'); //NAO FUNCIONA
        $('iframe').contents().find('html').css("--color_bg", '#000000'); //NAO FUNCIONA
    },1000)
});
```

Reparem que `$('.title', iframe.contents()).html('teste');` funciona perfeitamente.
Se eu fizer `$(":root").css("--color_bg", '#000000');` dentro do iframe também funciona sem problema.

Alguém tem ideia como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 0):

Depois de alguma pesquisa é testes arranjei uma soulção, não sei se é a mais elegante mas funciona:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('html').get(0).style.setProperty("--color_bg", "#000");
```

ou

```
$(":root", iframe.contents()).get(0).style.setProperty("--color_bg", "#000");
```